# Correct way to set PS1 prompt over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, prompt, expect

I am trying to set the PS1 prompt dynamically on the my remote machine. The idea is that when I will do ssh to the remote machine, I will also send the value which will set as a prompt for that remote machine. I already have an expect script which do automatic ssh login to the remote machine. Now I am trying to modifying the script in such a way that it will do automatic ssh along with setting the PS1 prompt with the value passed over ssh.  Below is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password Mayy@029Mayy@029
# now connect using ssh
spawn ssh -t vivek.gagrani@10.128.31.29  "'export PS1='bvdev@429[\w]#'; exec bash -l"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

On executing the above script I am getting error. `Inavalid command name w while executing \w`.

I am not sure if I am approaching it in correct way? Is my script correct for this task. Please help me

Comment: I don't know the quoting rules of `expect` from the top of my head, by my guess is that you will have to escape the `\w` in the string and remove the `'`.

Comment: Other than that, other people solve that problem differently, simply by having the shell running on the remote check whether the user is logged in locally or remotely, and adjust the prompt as desired. This can be really easy in the `~/.bashrc` on the target machine!

Comment: You have an odd number of single quotes. Sometimes that is OK, but I don't think so here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would like to do the way you are suggesting, setting the prompt from .bashrc file. But, we have different VM machines and .bashrc file is common for every VM. So I am not sure how can I set the dynamic PS1 prompt in .bashrc file such that for each VM, PS1 prompt should be set individually from the .bashrc file. The one idea which came in my mind is that the passing PS1 prompt over ssh for each VM. Please let me know if there is some other way possible. Thank you for giving your input

Comment: What information would you like the prompt to contain? Could you give an example?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Every VM has different number, for example `vdev423, vdev424, vdev425 etc`. So If I do ssh to vdev423 then prompt should set as `vdev@423[~]#:`, similarly if I do ssh to vdev424, then prompt should set as `vdev@424[~]#:` .  Please note that `.bashrc` file is common for every VM. so I was just wondering in `.bashrc` file how can I identify that which vdev user has done the ssh.

Comment: Do the VMs know their own number, e.g. through their hostname or IP address?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, `hostname` will give the vm number and  I am able to solve it.  In my `.bashrc` file I have done 
      `export PS1="hostname | sed -r 's/.{5}/&@/g'[\w]#"`
and after this I am able to achieve what I wanted. Thank you for guiding

Comment: @sachu somehow it seems you didn't copy here the actual command you used. Your command wouldn't work. Your prompt will literally be `hostname | sed -r 's/.{5}/&@/g'[\w]#`.

Comment: @aviro, I am sorry , here is the correct command `export PS1="\`hostname | sed -r 's/.{5}/&@/g'\`[\w]#"`. I am using `sed` to insert `@` after fifth character for my VM machine PS1 prompt. Without `sed` the command would look like `export PS1="\`hostname\`[\w]#"`

Answer (score 1):

Because expect is an extension of Tcl, we have to be aware of the rules of Tcl syntax

```
spawn ssh -t vivek.gagrani@10.128.31.29  "'export PS1='bvdev@429[\w]#'; exec bash -l"
```

Within double quotes, Tcl uses square brackets as the command substitution mechanism. Additionally, backslashes are acted upon: `\w` is not a special character (like `\t` is).

You'll want to use Tcl's non-interpolating quoting mechanism (like the shell's single quotes), which is curly brackets

```
spawn ssh -t vivek.gagrani@10.128.31.29  {export PS1='bvdev@429[\w]#'; exec bash -l}
```

**However**, `bash -l` will process the user's dotfiles, so the exported PS1 you have set will most likely be ignored.

```
spawn ssh -t vivek.gagrani@10.128.31.29  {
    export PS1='bvdev@429[\w]#'
    exec bash --noprofile --norc -i
}
```

However (again), I would not do that. I'd send the desired PS1 after logging in

```
spawn ssh -t vivek.gagrani@10.128.31.29 
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"
send -- {PS1='bvdev@429[\w]#'}
send -- "\r"
interact
```